# How did Calvin get Hugh's leg?

Tags: life-2017

In **Life**, how did Calvin get Hugh's leg? Since Hugh and his crew members were together.

Comment: Hugh sort of *let* him. Or at least he didn't say anything when he saw Calvin.

Comment: Related [movies.se] question: [**How did Calvin end up there without being seen?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70905/11244)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calvin attached himself to Hugh's legs when they were sealing off the ship (the scene where camera is shown from Calvin's perspective).

There are two theories, why he didn't notice/didn't told anyone that Calvin is on his leg:

1. Hugh's legs were disabled, which means, he doesn't feel anything where it comes to touch etc.
2. Hugh noticed Calvin, but his obession to new life form was so enormous, he couldn't just leave Calvin in vacuum and let it die. When Hugh is dying, he says that Calvin is just like us - trying to survive and we can't judge him for killing people to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

Hugh knew it was there, he looked at the leg it was on and kind of touched it before he passed out. He also told everyone he was sorry but never finished his follow up sentence, which I assume was him about to tell them what he let Calvin do.

On on to the real question. Calvin was intent eating Hugh's leg. Why the hell would you shock it? Hugh was dead anyways. I'd of tried to get to the escape pods while it was preoccupied.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, could you [edit] it to make it clearer?